# need only link as an output

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, data-cleaning

I have multiple html tag I want to extract only content of 1st href="..." for example this single line of data.

```
<a class="product-link" data-styleid="1424359" href="/tops/biba/biba-beige--pink-women-floral-print-top/1424359/buy?src=search"><img _src="http://assets.myntassets.com/h_240,q_95,w_180/v1/assets/images/1424359/2016/9/28/11475053941748-BIBA-Beige--Pink-Floral-Print-Kurti-7191475053941511-1_mini.jpg" _src2="http://assets.myntassets.com/h_307,q_95,w_230/v1/assets/images/1424359/2016/9/28/11475053941748-BIBA-Beige--Pink-Floral-Print-Kurti-7191475053941511-1_mini.jpg" alt="BIBA Beige &amp; Pink Women Floral Print Top" class="lazy loading thumb" onerror="this.className='thumb error'" onload="this.className='thumb'"/><div class="brand">Biba</div><div class="product">Beige &amp; Pink Women Floral Print Top</div><div class="price">Rs. 899</div><div class="sizes">Sizes: S, L, XL, XXL</div></a>
```

I want only `/tops/biba/biba-beige--pink-women-floral-print-top/1424359/buy?src=search` as output

The code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

x=urllib.urlopen("http://www.myntra.com/tops-tees-menu/")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')
for i in soup2.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'product-link'}):
    print i
    print i.find('a')['href']
```

Comment: `i` is bound to each <a> element.  And then you try to `find()` <a> elements _within_ the <a> elements bound to `i`. Those nested links don't exist.  You want the href attribute from the `i` object directly instead. `i` is a very bad name for something that isn't an integral number, especially as loop variable. This confuses most programmers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single "product link", just use `find()`:

```
soup2.find('a', attrs={'class': 'product-link'})["href"]
```

Note that you can use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) location technique as well:

```
soup2.select_one('a.product-link')["href"]
```